# Dual dnsmasq name resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, dnsmasq

For resilience, I have two dnsmasq instances providing both local DNS and DHCP. DHCP is configured to offer separate IP ranges from each instance.

I then add IP reservations to the /etc/dnsmasq.d/99-static-dhcp.conf files on each instance, and hostnames to the /etc/hosts file on each instance - basically so that they're the same.

This largely works fine, but with this approach I need to give all devices I want to use/interact with remotely a known/static IP.

If I don't, then one of the dnsmasq servers will assign and allocate the dynamic IP and will be able to provide name resolution for that host, but the other dnsmasq instance won't know about it, so won't be able to resolve the IP.

Given many clients (e.g. Windows) only perform DNS lookups against one server, this can mean that the client won't be able to get the IP address for this dynamic host unless it happens to hit the right dnsmasq instance.

I know there is a way to have one DNS server send requests to another, but I tried this before and seemed to get into a loop.

What would be the correct way to configure both dnsmasq instances to query each other if they themselves cannot resolve the local IP addresses?

Thanks